# Issue with Spark tutorial

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I'm trying out
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.1/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed.scala
example.

But what should be the input at specified port number?

Answer (score 0):

Use This command on your terminal.

```
nc -lk 9999
```

It would be something like this :

```
# TERMINAL 1:
# Running Netcat

$ nc -lk 9999
apache spark
apache hadoop
```

The output would be :

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+------+-----+
| value|count|
+------+-----+
|apache|    1|
| spark|    1|
+------+-----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+------+-----+
| value|count|
+------+-----+
|apache|    2|
| spark|    1|
|hadoop|    1|
+------+-----+
...
```

And see the output accordingly.

Its better documented here: https://home.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-branch-2.0-docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#quick-example